# sort object using custom sorter doesn't work

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have this custom sorter:

```
 public class AlphaNumericSorter : IComparer<string>
    {
        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            return SafeNativeMethods.StrCmpLogicalW(x, y);
        }
    }

    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    internal static class SafeNativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string psz1, string psz2);
    }
```

I want to sort my all objects but it just sort one of my column and i have to pass my column.
I need to sort this type of list based on`jointnumber`

```
List<ViewTestPackageHistorySheet> testList = _reportTestPackageHistorySheetRepository.ShowReport(Id).ToList();

        testList.Sort(new AlphaNumericSorter());
```

I got this error :

```
'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<ViewDomainClass.Report.TestPackage.ViewTestPackageHistorySheet>'
```

But this works :

```
  List<string> testList = _reportTestPackageHistorySheetRepository.ShowReport(Id).Select(i=>i.JointNumber).ToList();
        testList.Sort(new AlphaNumericSorter());
```

Comment: `'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<ViewDomainClass.Report.TestPackage.ViewTestPackageHistorySheet>'` is not an error, it's just a namespace? What is the actual error you get? `"But this works : etc..."` and if your next code line works, then whats your question?

Comment: Why implement a costum sorter for strings?

Comment: Vote down please comment!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to implement is like: `IComparer<ViewTestPackageHistorySheet>`

You want to compare `ViewTestPackageHistorySheet` instead of `string`

Something like:

```
public class AlphaNumericSorter : IComparer<ViewTestPackageHistorySheet>
{
    public int Compare(ViewTestPackageHistorySheet x, ViewTestPackageHistorySheet y)
    {
        return SafeNativeMethods.StrCmpLogicalW(x.JointNumber, y.JointNumber);
    }
}

[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
internal static class SafeNativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string psz1, string psz2);
}
```

---

Use it like:

```
var result = _reportTestPackageHistorySheetRepository.ShowReport(Id).ToList();

result.Sort(new AlphaNumericSorter());
```